# When executed aws ecs update-service is block my terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

I am automating a CD process with deployment on AWS ECS, however, when executing ***aws ecs update-service --cluster MYCLUSTER --service MYSERVICE***, it is blocking my terminal with response json from the service's task-definition, how can I execute ***aws ecs update-service*** without blocking my terminal?

My script is very simple:

```
docker build --no-cache -t my-image .
docker push my-image

aws ecs update-service --cluster MYCLUSTER --service MYSERVICE --force-new-deployment --region us-east-1

./another-scripts.sh
```

another-scripts.sh only runs after pressing q in the terminal

I tried running aws ***ecs update-service --cluster MYCLUSTER --service MYSERVICE***, and hoping the terminal wouldn't block with the json response so the next commands could be run in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is [paginating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html) the output. You need to add the `--no-paginate` argument to the CLI command.

Comment: i already run
aws ecs update-service --cluster MYCLUSTER --service MYSERVICE --force-new-deployment --region us-east-1 --no-paginate but it didn't work

Comment: --no-paginate didn't work, so I ended up using another approach, passing a: | grep -E 'taskDefinition' at the end of the command, so I see the task lines without holding up the terminal.